# The Notation Y ← A.B in ASM charts

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

I am a physicist trying to get to grips with system-verilog and am trying to understand ASM charts, I think I have got to grips with them but some of the notation is a mystery to me still and I am having trouble finding the answers.

If the following expression appears on an ASM chart "Y ← A.B"

I gather that Y takes the value on the right hand side of the expression in the next clock cycle and keeps that value for further clock cycles (unless modified elsewhere). However I am not familiar with what "A.B" means.

My guess is that it means A AND B (as in Y = A & B, if A and B = 1 then Y = 1). Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I think it a logical anding and not a bitwise one. `Y=A&&B` is logical AND and `Y=A&B` is a bitwise AND.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks, I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears ASM charts share the notation of boolean algebra, where a dot represents a boolean AND.

SomeRandomPhysicist